# Zeta series with MacLaurin.

Tags: analytic-number-theory, analytic-continuation

I want to show $\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}+\frac{1}{2}+ (s+1)s \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{ G(x)}{x^{s+2}} dx.$  With $G(x)= \int_{0}^{x} (\{u\} -1/2) du$ for Re(s)>-1

By the Mac Laurin sommation formula, I have 
$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}+\frac{1}{2}- s \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{ (\{x\}-1/2)}{x^{s+1}} dx.$

Here is what I have tried so far:
 $- s \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{ (\{x\}-1/2)}{x^{s+1}} dx=- s \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{G^{(1)}(x)}{x^{s+1}} dx+s \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{2 x^{s+1}} $= $ - s \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{G^{(1)}(x)}{x^{s+1}} dx+ \frac{1}{2}$.
I then integrated by part.

$ - s \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{G^{(1)}(x)}{x^{s+1}} dx+ \frac{1}{2}=-s \left(  \frac{G(x)}{x^{s+1}} |_1^{\infty}+ (s+1)\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{G(x) dx}{x^{s+2}} \right)$

I am stuck after this.
Can anyone help?

Comment: You're doing everything correctly! Just note that $G'(x) = \{x\}-\frac12$, not $G'(x) = \{x\}$.

Comment: @GregMartin How can i finish the proof? Im stuck

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? I think you've accomplished more than you think you have.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show the [Abel summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula), for $Re(s) > 1$  :
$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} = \int_{1-\epsilon}^\infty (\sum_{n=1}^\infty \delta(x-n)) x^{-s} dx = \int_1^\infty \lfloor x \rfloor s x^{-s-1}dx$$
That is just an integration by parts with a distribution $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \delta(x-n) = \frac{d}{dx} \lfloor x \rfloor$. If you don't like distributions, no problem, write that $\int_n^{n+1} \lfloor x \rfloor s x^{-s-1} dx = n (n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s}) = n^{1-s}-(n+1)^{1-s}+ (n+1)^{-s}$ so that $\int_1^N \lfloor x \rfloor s x^{-s-1} dx = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} (n^{1-s}-(n+1)^{1-s}+ (n+1)^{-s}) = -N^{1-s}+\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}$ and the result follows.

Once this is done, you get $\zeta(s) =  \frac{s}{s-1}-s\int_1^\infty \{x \} x^{-s-1}dx = 1+\frac{1}{s-1}-s\int_1^\infty \{x \} x^{-s-1}dx$ $= 1+\frac{1}{s-1}-1/2-s\int_1^\infty (\{x \}-1/2) x^{-s-1}dx$ and integrating by parts you get your formula (up to a minus sign)

$$\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{s-1}+1/2-s(s+1)\int_1^\infty (\int_0^x(\{t \}-1/2)dt) x^{-s-2}dx$$

Finally, since $\int_0^x(\{t \}-1/2)dt = \mathcal{O}(1)$ it converges and it is analytic for $Re(s)> -1$ and hence it is the analytic continuation of $\zeta(s)$.